# Google Play paid apps; are countries with non-settable prices still charged for the app?

Tags: android, google-play

So, I jumped through all the hoops to start charging for my apps, but whilst writing up the draft info for my soon-to-release app I noticed that out of all the countries I'm able to distribute to, only a handful of them have the ability to set individual prices. All of the other countries not only don't give you that option, but they don't show any currency conversion for it.

Does Google charge them the default currency (in my case, $0.99 USD), or do they do day-of-purchase currency conversions of their country, or do they just distribute them for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the price specifically for that country if (and only if) you've targeted that particular country for selling your app.  You can either set the price manually, or use Auto-Fill to set a price in each of the targeted countries based on the exchange rate and your home currency price.  From [Selling Apps in Multiple Currencies](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1169947)

> For each country that you wish sell your app in, check the box next to that country and enter a price. You cannot target a particular country without entering a price. If you select Auto Fill, Google Play will populate the other currency fields with a converted price based on your home currency price. The autofill price is provided for your convenience only -- you may choose to use it or set your own price. The autofill conversion uses the daily exchange rate on the day that you set the price; it does not float.

If you don't have the ability to target that specific country, it might be that it's not currently possible to sell apps there via Google Play.

Comment: Sorry, but that option of setting prices simply doesn't appear for me. I can't find any documentation on why this is happening. I see the table, but the part where you choose the price is empty